# Solr spatial search with input point and query which polygon within

Tags: search, solr, polygon, geospatial, point

I have some polygons indexed in Solr. Is it possible to query with a point(lat,lon) and see which polygon has that point inside?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is possible and described here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4
Your Solr Version must be 4 or higher and you have to import the JTS jar-file which you can get from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/ 
You have to define a field with a fieldType of location_rpt

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
           spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
           distErrPct="0.025"
           maxDistErr="0.000009"
           units="degrees"
        />
```

in the schema.xml. Then you have to index the polygons like:

```
<field name="geo">POLYGON((-10 30, -40 40, -10 -20, 40 20, 0 0, -10 30))</field>
```

But i think you already did it this way because you wrote that you already have them indexed.

For the query you simply have to use the filter query `fq=geo:"Intersects(10.12 50.02)"` where `10.12` and `50.02` represent the latitude and longitude of your point.

Comment: Why the need for the external JTS jar file? is it still required for the latest SOLR?

Comment: Because from solr 6.x.x the JTS library is not included anymore.
just download the jar files from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/ and include  them into solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
then restart solr

Answer (score 0):

We need the external JTS jar file to index Polygon shapes in first place.