# how to search within a polygon in solr 4.10

Tags: solr, geospatial

Hi below is data xml which I have inserted in solr.

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="id">3007</field>
  <field name="name">Autauga</field>
  <field name="coord">POLYGON((-10 30,-40 40,-10 -20,40 20,0 0,-10 30))</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

There will be many documents of such type denoting separate regions
Now please let me know How can I search that document having  a given point which lies in the range of polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Solr Version must be 4 or higher and you have to import the JTS jar-file. You also have to define a field with a fieldType of "solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType". Then you can query using a filter query like `fq=geo:"Intersects(10.12 50.02)"`.

But please see my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368588/solr-spatial-search-with-input-point-and-query-which-polygon-within) or http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4 for more detailed information.

Comment: The wiki has been updated and can now be found here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search