# Failed to install jts library on Solr 6.4.2

Tags: solr, jetty, polygon, jts

I just installed Solr-6.4.2 and tried to install the JTS library [like here explained](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4) by copying all JTS library files to the /solr-6.4.2/server/solr-webapp/WEB-INF/lib directory.

Then configured the managed-schema by adding

```
  <fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
           spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
           distErrPct="0.025"
           maxDistErr="0.000009"
           units="degrees"
        />

<field name="geo"  type="location_rpt"  indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true" />
```

and started it in /bin with ./solr start (jetty)

But when i visit the solr interface it says:

```
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
> Could not load conf for core polygon: Can't load schema
> /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema:
> Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
```

It looks to me that the library is not found or not automatically loaded (as it should be according to tutorials).

Can you help me?
Here is the log file:

```
2017-03-11 15:44:57.061 INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.CorePropertiesLocator Cores are: [polygon]
2017-03-11 15:44:57.067 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader [null] Added 8 libs to classloader, from paths: [/home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/lib]
2017-03-11 15:44:57.117 INFO  (main) [   ] o.e.j.s.Server Started @777ms
2017-03-11 15:44:57.174 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader [polygon] Added 59 libs to classloader, from paths: [/home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/contrib/clustering/lib, /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/contrib/extraction/lib, /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/contrib/langid/lib, /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/contrib/velocity/lib, /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/dist]
2017-03-11 15:44:57.209 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.c.SolrConfig Using Lucene MatchVersion: 6.4.2
2017-03-11 15:44:57.298 INFO  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.s.IndexSchema [polygon] Schema name=example-data-driven-schema
2017-03-11 15:44:57.385 WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.c.SolrResourceLoader Solr loaded a deprecated plugin/analysis class [solr.SynonymFilterFactory]. Please consult documentation how to replace it accordingly.
2017-03-11 15:44:57.535 WARN  (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.s.AbstractSpatialFieldType Replace 'com.spatial4j.core' with 'org.locationtech.spatial4j' in your schema.
2017-03-11 15:44:57.556 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1) [   x:polygon] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [polygon]: Could not load conf for core polygon: Can't load schema /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core polygon: Can't load schema /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:888)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$3(CoreContainer.java:542)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't load schema /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:598)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.<init>(ManagedIndexSchema.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:491)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: schema fieldtype location_rpt(org.apache.solr.schema.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) invalid arguments:{units=degrees}
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.setArgs(FieldType.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:191)
    ... 16 more
2017-03-11 15:44:57.558 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be created
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [polygon]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$4(CoreContainer.java:570)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [polygon]
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:903)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$3(CoreContainer.java:542)
    at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:197)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core polygon: Can't load schema /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:888)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't load schema /home/spatial/solr-6.4.2/server/solr/polygon/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:598)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:183)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.<init>(ManagedIndexSchema.java:104)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:491)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: schema fieldtype location_rpt(org.apache.solr.schema.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) invalid arguments:{units=degrees}
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldType.setArgs(FieldType.java:202)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:165)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.init(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:53)
    at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:191)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the interface was recently changed and older examples found on stackoverflow, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368588/solr-spatial-search-with-input-point-and-query-which-polygon-within) are not working with the most current solr version (6.4.2). The most current documentation is [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search)

A configuration example which will work:

```
  <fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
    spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
    autoIndex="true"
    distErrPct="0.025"
    maxDistErr="0.001"
    distanceUnits="kilometers" />
```

I. e. `distanceUnits` is now used instead of `units`, etc. and `degrees` as attribute seems to raise an error.

The initial code I used raised errors in the most current solr version.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: schema fieldtype location_rpt(org.apache.solr.schema.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType) invalid arguments:{units=degrees}
```